# Unable to Get Eloquent to Automatically Create Joins

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

**I would like to use built-in ORM functionality in Laravel's Eloquent ORM to automatically join the tournaments and countries tables together when running a query**, and return the data set that includes tournament data as well as its associated country data.

That is, I want Eloquent to recognize the foreign key relationship automatically so that I can just run a query (e.g. `Tournament:: with('Country')->all()`) that will return the entire set of tournament and country data.

## Query that I Would Like to Replicate in Eloquent

```
SELECT * FROM tournaments LEFT JOIN countries ON tournaments.country_id = countries.id
```

## Expected Result in PHP

I expect to receive an array of Tournament objects (in PHP), where a single Tournament object would look like:

- tournaments.id
- tournaments.year
- tournaments.country_id
- tournaments.created_at
- tournaments.updated_at
- countries.id
- countries.code
- countries.name
- countries.url
- countries.created_at
- countries.updated_at

## Failed attempts that I've made so far

I ran all of these attempts in a dummy controller method and output the result as a formatted string to the profiler.

### Failed Attempt #1:

PHP code in the dummy controller:

```
$tournaments = Tournament::with('Country')->all();
```

Generates the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `tournaments`
```

Attempt #1 returns:

An array containing Tournament objects that only include the columns in the tournaments table.

### Failed Attempt #2

PHP code in the dummy controller:

```
$tournaments = Tournament::with('Country')->first();
```

Generates the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tournament_id' in 'where clause'

SQL: SELECT * FROM `countries` WHERE `tournament_id` IN (?)

Bindings: array (
0 => '1',
)
```

### Other Failed Attempts

I've tried various combinations of naming conventions (e.g. columns, tables, etc.) to no avail. I've also tried creating the query in Fluent, which worked fine, but required me to specify the joins which is what I'm trying to avoid.

## My Environment

- PHP: 5.3.13
- MySQL: 5.1.53
- Laravel: 3.2.3

## Relationship Between Tables

- one-to-one relationship
- A tournament must have a country (there's a foreign key constraint to enforce it)
- A country can belong to many other relations (e.g. a participant, not shown here, has a country of birth)

## Countries Table

```
CREATE TABLE `countries` (                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,                                                                                                                                                                                                       
`code` varchar(4) NOT NULL,                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
`name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,                                                                                                                                                                                                                
`url` varchar(25) NOT NULL,                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
`created_at` datetime NOT NULL,                                                                                                                                                                                                             
`updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,                                                                                                                                                                                                            
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
UNIQUE KEY `countries_code_unique` (`code`),                                                                                                                                                                                               
KEY `countries_url_index` (`url`)                                                                                                                                                                                                          
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=28 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

## Tournaments Table

```
CREATE TABLE `tournaments` (                                                                                                                                                                                                             
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,                                                                                                                                                                                                       
`year` int(11) NOT NULL,                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
`country_id` int(11) NOT NULL,                                                                                                                                                                                                              
`created_at` datetime NOT NULL,                                                                                                                                                                                                             
`updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,                                                                                                                                                                                                             
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
UNIQUE KEY `tournaments_year_unique` (`year`),                                                                                                                                                                                             
KEY `tournaments_country_id_foreign` (`country_id`),                                                                                                                                                                                      
CONSTRAINT `tournaments_country_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`) REFERENCES `countries` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE                                                                                                                  
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=40 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

## Countries Model (countries.php)

```
class Country extends Eloquent {
    public static $timestamps = true;
    public static $table = 'countries';
}
```

## Tournaments Model (tournaments.php)

```
class Tournament extends Eloquent {
    public static $timestamps = true;

    public function country()
    {
        return $this->has_one('Country');
    }
}
```

Comment: Now that is a well written question, +1 to you sir.

Comment: Now that's a beautifully written question. Good job! :)

Comment: Just dropping this one: area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/46607/laravel

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Clearly `with('Country')` or `with('country')` doesn't do any different due to the fact that he managed to get following error:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tournament_id' in 'where clause'

SQL: SELECT * FROM `countries` WHERE `tournament_id` IN (?)
```

What wrong is how the relationship is defined: **A tournament must have a country** would be a tournament need to belong to a country, and not has one country. So to solve this change the relationship to

```
public function country()
{
    return $this->belongs_to('Country');
}
```

Comment: Hi @crynobone, thank you for the response. Apologies for the extremely late reply. I switched focus and forgot about this question and specific issue. Implementing your solution didn't quite get the desired result. It created two separate queries, one on the "country" table and another on the "tournament" table. My preferred result would have been a single joined query that matches the one I provided in my original question under the "Query that I Would Like to Replicate in Eloquent" heading. I will come back to this issue again and update this thread if I make headway.

Comment: Laravel eager loading doesn't use JOIN query, which is different from other ORM approach, being said that it still possible to use Eloquent with join using Fluent Query Builder structure. ```Tournament::query()->join('countries' ...);```

Comment: Thanks for the response, crynobone! It's too bad, since I really wanted to use Eloquent to generate queries as much as possible. That said, Fluent Query Builder is more than sufficient.

Comment: @GrahamKennedy This may be a late reply. But the reason why you are not getting desired result is that you use `->all()` instead of `->get()` method. Use the `->get()` method and you will be amazed

Comment: @GrahamKennedy this answer is correct and deserves to be picked as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Eloquent docs:

> Note: All methods available on the query builder are also available when querying Eloquent models.

So with that in mind something like:

```
DB::table("tournament")->join("countries","tournaments.country_id","=","countries.id")->get();
```

Should be replicable in Eloquent. I personally use the query builder version just now which you may want to use but I will try and test with Eloquent when I get the chance and update this.

**UPDATE:**

Yep, using Eloquent's query builder methods you can have:

```
Tournament::join("countries","tournaments.country_id","=","countries.id")->get();
```

This will return a Tournament model that includes the fields of both tables.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Your 'with' clause asks for 'Country', but your code declares it as 'country'.

So, should:

```
$tournaments = Tournament::with('Country')->all();
```

Be:

```
$tournaments = Tournament::with('country')->all();
```

Because in your Tournaments Model, you've defined this as:

```
public function country()
{
    return $this->has_one('Country');
}
```

Does making this change solve it?

Comment: Hi @James Healey, thank you for your input. Unfortunately the casing didn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure your relationship is declared in your Tournament model:

```
public function country() {
    return $this->has_one('Country');
}
```

Also, you will have to declare the opposite in your Country model:

```
public function tournament() {
    return $this->belongs_to('Tournament');
}
```

At this point, you can access the tournament object associated with the country object like so:

```
$tournaments = Tournament::with('country')->all();
foreach ($tournaments as $tournament) {
    echo $tournament->country;
}
```

Let me know if this display each corresponding country to the tournament.